# carousel image loop with database

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get the image for the carousel by looping the database image. in the js, I have managed to loop all the image name out in home.js, however, I am not sure how am I suppose to show it in the HTML? my HTML code only managed to get the latest image and show it once in the carousel. My 2nd and 3rd carousel does not show anything. My main aim is to get the image that are available in the database and show it in the carousel

Am I suppose to use append or attr? when I use append, I did not get any image. I have declared webserverURL in my other JS file.

`$("#imgEventPicture").append("src", webserverURL() + "/images/" + event_Img + "_s");`

`$("#imgEventPicture").attr("src", webserverURL() + "/images/" + event_Img + "_s");`

**home.html**

```html
    <div class="container">
                        <h2>Upcoming Event</h2>
                        <div id="Sideusername"></div>



                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <!-- Indicators -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>

                            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                <div class="item active">
                                    <!--<img src="images/halloween.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">-->
                                    <img id="imgEventPicture" height="100">
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                    <!--<img src="images/familyday.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">-->
                                    <img id="imgEventPicture" height="100">
                                </div>
                                


                            </div>

                            <!-- Left and right controls -->
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**home.js**

```js
//Profile Section
    function getEvent() {
        var url = serverURL() + "/getevent.php";
        

        var JSONObject = {
            "user_name": localStorage.getItem("userid"),
          
        };

        
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: JSONObject,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (arr) {
                _getEventResult(arr);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
                alert(error);
                validationMsg();
            }
        });
    }
    

    function _getEventResult(arr) {
       
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            event_id = arr[i].event_id;

            event_Img = arr[i].event_Img;
            event_title = arr[i].event_title;
            event_description = arr[i].event_description;
            event_date = arr[i].event_date;
            event_time = arr[i].event_time;
            event_location = arr[i].event_location;
            staff_ID = arr[i].staff_ID;


            console.log("event_id>>" + event_id);
            console.log("event_Img>>" + event_Img);
           
            
           // $("#imgEventPicture").append("src", webserverURL() + "/images/" + event_Img + "_s");
         $("#imgEventPicture").attr("src", webserverURL() + "/images/" + event_Img + "_s");
            alert("event_Img" + event_Img);
        }
    }
```

**getevent.php**

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

include("global.php");

$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$event_id = $_GET['event_id'];

//$result = $conn->query("select * from Event where event_id = '" . $event_id . "'");
$result = $conn->query("select * from Event ");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
 $outp .= '{"event_id":"'  . $rs["event_id"] . '",';
 $outp .= '"event_Img":"'   . $rs["event_Img"]  . '"}';
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```